# setting express js static files and including them in template files

Tags: node.js, express

I have set my static folder to public (in the root of my app folder) within the app.js.
But still the handlebars layout files when linking the css files, could not find the files within the public folder.

```
// app.js code:
// init app
var app = express();

// view engine
app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'views'));
app.set('view engine','handlebars');
app.engine('handlebars',expressHandlebars({defaultLayout:'layout'}));

// middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(cookieParser());

// set static folder
app.set(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));



handlebars layout file:
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
```

Comment: have you added `var path = require('path');` ??

Comment: yep. its added.

Comment: Any error? This is my [code](https://kopy.io/0twKg), I guess there is some problem with your app.js sequence of setting configuration of views and path

Comment: 404 not found response

Comment: Use absolute URL's (`href="/css/bootstrap.min/css"`)

Comment: still its the same. how does this linking work in express? if i add the public dir path, then where ever my handlebars layout is within the views dir it should work right?

Answer (score 3):

First of all you must use absolute path as mentioned by [robertklep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893780/robertklep) in comments.

Now the problem, you are using `app.set` thats the problem, you have to use `.use` method not `.set`.

Now about how you should structure your directory, I recommend assigning a directory path like '/public' for accessing public files. It can be done like this :

```
//app.use not .set
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
//see the first argument in above line it assigns which directory path is used to access the public file through URL
```

After this is done you can access the files you need like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
```

Comment: ya, this helped me, the problem was with app.set. now it got solved